# Flutter - How to create a native splash screen with text and line progress indicator?

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I'm creating a splash screen using Native Splash.

How to create a splash screen with a row of text and a line progress indicator (like below)?

[image]

```
dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19

flutter_native_splash:
 android: true
 ios: true
 web: false

color: "#42a5f5"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the native android splash supports custom text and widgets.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Android 12 recently added support for splash animations

Comment: So, you could possibly use a custom animation to achieve this